# $_POST[] not catching HTML form input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a strange problem, I am passing data from an email form (HTML5) to ajax/JSON and returning `false` so the page does not redirect to the `php` script after the submit button is pressed.

If I put commas seperating each `data` param (`$email, $name, $message`), only 'name' and 'email' get passed to `$_POST[]`, leaving out the value of`$message`.

However if there are no commas between the params all the inputs are caught by `$_POST[]`.

For example (**with** commas): (does not redirect to `php` script but `$message` value is not caught in `$_POST[]`)

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function (evt) {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('Scripts/php/sendemail.php',{
        name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
        email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
        message: $('input[name=message]').val()
    }, function(data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Output:

```
$name=foo
$email=bar
$message=null
```

Page returns `false`

(**without** commas): (redirects to `php` script but `$message` value is caught in `$_POST[]`)

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function (evt) {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('Scripts/php/sendemail.php',{
        name: $('input[name=name]').val()
        email: $('input[name=email]').val()
        message: $('input[name=message]').val()
    }, function(data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false; (does not redirect to `php`)
});
```

Output:

```
$name=foo
$email=bar
$message=bar
```

HTML Form:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="Scripts/php/sendemail.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">
                    Send Message
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS for form:

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function (evt) {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('Scripts/php/sendemail.php',
        {name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
        email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
        message: $('input[name=message]').val()
        }, function(data) {
                $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
           },'json');
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

PHP handler:

```
  <?php

header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Email sent! Thankyou :)'
);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'query';
$message = $_POST['message'];
$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'keilcarpenter01@gmail.com';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: visitor');

echo json_encode($status);
#start buffering (all activity to the buffer)
ob_start() ;

# dumps to buffer
var_dump($_POST) ;

# dump buffered $classvar to $outStringVar
$outStringVar = ob_get_contents() ;

# open your file with append, read, write perms
# (be sure to check your file perms)
$fp=fopen('dmp.txt','a+');

# write output to file & close it
fwrite($fp, $outStringVar );
fclose($fp);

# clean the buffer & stop buffering output
ob_end_clean() ;
die;
```

In this case how does the `comma` seperatores determine what `input` by `form` gets caught by `$_POST[]`?

Comment: To support community, Please vote up the answers which solved your problem and anyone's answer as correct.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the jquery for get value of textarea, try following code for that :-

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function (evt) {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('Scripts/php/sendemail.php',
        {name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
        email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
        message: $('textarea[name=message]').val()
        }, function(data) {
                $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
           },'json');
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
message: $('textarea[name=message]').val()
```

Comment: I feel bad for not accepting your answer, I accepted the other because he/she provided the entire explanation. But because you are correct also i voted you up :) thanks alot for your answer!